# $Pr(X>2E(X)) \le \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: statistics

How to show $Pr(X>2E(X))\le 1/2$ given that $X$ is a continuous random variable and $P(X\le 0)=0$? $E(X)$ here is the mean of $X$.

I started with the definition of $E(X)$ for the continuous case. Then, I broke the integral into the integral from -infinity to 0 + the integral from 0 to +infinity. Since $Pr(X\le 0)=0$, the first term vanishes by using integration by parts. The second term will be greater or equal to the integral from $0$ to $x$ for any $x$ in the open interval $(0,+\infty)$. I got stuck here. I am trying to end up with an inequality relationship between $E(X)$ and the density probability function $f(x)$ so I can use that in the definition of $Pr(X>2*E(x))$. Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: If the average weight of an egg is 2.3 ounces, it’s not possible for more than half of all eggs to weigh more than 4.6 ounces.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For every $c>0$ we can prove [Markov's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3037798/215011):
$$
P(X>c)=\int_{x=c}^\infty f(x)\,dx \stackrel{(a)}\le\int_{x=c}^\infty \frac xc f(x)\,dx\le\frac1c \int_0^\infty xf(x)\,dx\stackrel{(b)}=\frac1c E(X)
$$
In (a) we use the fact that $x\ge c$ implies $\frac xc\ge 1$. For (b) we use the fact that $P(X\le0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a continuous random variable for this. Non-negative is enough. $EX \geq EXI_{X>2EX} \geq E(2EX)I_{X>2EX}=2EXP(X>2EX)$ so $P(X>2EX) \leq \frac {EX} {2EX}=\frac  1 2$

Comment: Dear Kavi, thank you for your help. Non-negativity is not one of the assumptions in the question. Could you please tell me from where you deduced that?

Comment: @Althaqel $P(X\leq 0)=0$ so P(X>0)=1-0=1$. So $X \geq 0$ almost surely.